# How to move index.html to the top of brach gh-pages in Github?

Tags: github, readme

my site on Github only shows the ReadMe file. I have found out, that it is possible to move the index.html file to the top of the gh-pages branch.
But how to do that? When i click on "upload files" then nothing happens? Can someone help maybe?